# How can I add `charset` in php part?

Tags: php

I wrote following code for my page with `utf-8` charset command:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">
<title> . . . </title>
<style type="text/css";>
   <!--
   .mystyle {
   font-size:12px;
   }
   -->
</style>
<?php 
 $myDirectory = opendir(".");
 while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
     $dirArray[] = $entryName;
 }
 closedir($myDirectory);
 $indexCount = count($dirArray)-2;
 print("<table border=0 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 class='mystyle'>\n");
 print("<tr> . . . </tr>\n");
.
.
.
 print("<td align=right>");
 print(number_format(filesize($dirArray[$index])/1024));
}
.
.
.
print("<td><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">
.
.
.
}
print("</table>\n");
?>
```

When I run this code, it is run in correct mode, but with writing files in a list, it doesn't work properly in `charset="utf-8"` mode. How can I add `charset` in `php` part?

Comment: The only thing I see you echoing out in PHP here is a filesize. Character set shouldn't matter at all here...?

Comment: You have to save the PHP file as UTF-8 in your editor, without a byte order mark (BOM)

Comment: @Code4R7 I've saved it in utf-8 mode.

Comment: @MyGlasses That should do the trick, assuming that you've set an HTML5 doctype and that your webserver does not throw in a HTTP content encoding header that is different from UTF-8. Ohw and please **do** fix the quotes on your meta attribute, otherwise it still won't work.

Comment: As an aside, the modern version of the charset meta tag is `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the charset in php is made like this :

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8") ;
```

**NB** It should be sent before to write in the output, so, before your `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">`.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8") ;
?><!doctype html><html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">
...
```

Comment: Thanks. It isn't sent to new output, it is part of the same file. Is your solution work in this case?

Comment: I think it is. Put the PHP code in the begining of your PHP file.

Comment: For `<!doctype ...` please read `<!DOCTYPE html>`. And don't forget to save as UTF-8 without BOM, otherwise you get the famous 'headers are already sent' error.

Comment: Well what do you know, the doctype is case insensitive after all.. who would have thought!

Comment: @Code4R7 Thanks for your comment. I didn't take care about what I wrote. I usually writes it in lowercase.